# Mysql - XML like table with multiple values in same column

Tags: mysql

My question title is confusing, sorry about that.

I have one application that saves data in the database in XML'ish format, referencing keys and values.
The problem is that I have only one column with several values that corresponds to a certain key.

I need to have certain keys as columns but I am failing miserably to achieve that:

Below a sample of the table I have

```
xml_type    | xml_key | xml_content_key                                      | xml_content_value
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Archiv::144 | 144     | [1]{'Version'}[1]{'Carrier'}[1]{'Content'}           | 151
Archiv::144 | 144     | [1]{'Version'}[1]{'CarrierID'}[1]{'Content'}         | 5714141614
Archiv::144 | 144     | [1]{'Version'}[1]{'CustomerInterface'}[1]{'Content'} | 145
```

So, I can run this and have all the carriers:

```
select xml_content_key as Carrier, xml_content_value as 'Carrier Result'
from xml_storage xs where xml_content_key LIKE '%[1]{\'Version\'}[1]{\'Carrier\'}[1]{\'Content\'}%'
```

But how would I other keys from column xml_content_key to be shown as coluns.
I have tried nested selects but got "Returns more than one value", a join would not apply since this is on a single table.

In short, I would like to run a query to gather a few keys from column xml_content_key and have each in a new column.

Thank you.

Comment: MySQL allows you to store XML and JSON in columns. If you don't want to normalize your table design, use one of them rather than designing your own format.

Comment: In general, it's not easy to split up a column into an arbitrary number of results. That's why you should store arrays of data in separate rows in the first place.

Comment: Hello Barmar, thanks for the comment, this design is from one application the company I work for uses so no chance for me to change it at this time, can you point me in the direction of having XML, JSON as a column?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html

Comment: XML isn't a datatype, it's just functions that can parse XML in strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without knowing the schema of either your table or your XML document I'll have to make some assumptions. But I think this isn't too hard. First I'll write out the assumptions I'm making. Please correct me if these assumptions are wrong.**

It seems like you have a table in which `xml_content_key` is what should be the column name, and `xml_key` is what should be the row identifier. You only showed a very limited sample in your question, but my assumption would suggest that more data might look like this.

```
xml_type    | xml_key | xml_content_key                                      | xml_content_value
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Archiv::144 | 144     | [1]{'Version'}[1]{'Carrier'}[1]{'Content'}           | 151
Archiv::144 | 144     | [1]{'Version'}[1]{'CarrierID'}[1]{'Content'}         | 5714141614
Archiv::144 | 144     | [1]{'Version'}[1]{'CustomerInterface'}[1]{'Content'} | 145
Archiv::144 | 145     | [1]{'Version'}[1]{'Carrier'}[1]{'Content'}           | 123
Archiv::144 | 145     | [1]{'Version'}[1]{'CarrierID'}[1]{'Content'}         | 4567891234
Archiv::144 | 145     | [1]{'Version'}[1]{'CustomerInterface'}[1]{'Content'} | 567
Archiv::144 | 146     | [1]{'Version'}[1]{'Carrier'}[1]{'Content'}           | 891
Archiv::144 | 146     | [1]{'Version'}[1]{'CarrierID'}[1]{'Content'}         | 2345678912
Archiv::144 | 146     | [1]{'Version'}[1]{'CustomerInterface'}[1]{'Content'} | 345
```

And I think you're trying to write a query to reorganize it like this.

```
+---------+---------+------------+-------------------+
| xml_key | Carrier | CarrierID  | CustomerInterface |
+---------+---------+------------+-------------------+
|     144 |     151 | 5714141614 |               145 |
|     145 |     123 | 4567891234 |               567 |
|     146 |     891 | 2345678912 |               345 |
+---------+---------+------------+-------------------+
```

**If I'm wrong about this part then there's no point in reading on.** But if I'm right so far, then I'd like to highlight a quote from your question.

> ***a join would not apply since this is on a single table.***

You have been missing out on a great feature of SQL: [self joins](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/) are extremely useful in cases like this.

It appears that there are three "content keys" (or columns) for each `xml_key` (or row). We will join together all the `xml_content_key`'s that share the same `xml_key`, so that each row will describe a single `xml_key`. By the way, I'm assuming your table is named `xml_storage`.

```
SELECT xs1.xml_key AS 'xml_key',
       xs1.xml_content_value AS 'Carrier',
       xs2.xml_content_value AS 'CarrierID',
       xs3.xml_content_value AS 'CustomerInterface'
FROM       xml_storage xs1
INNER JOIN xml_storage xs2 ON xs2.xml_key = xs1.xml_key
INNER JOIN xml_storage xs3 ON xs3.xml_key = xs1.xml_key
WHERE  xs1.xml_content_key LIKE "%[1]{'Version'}[1]{'Carrier'}[1]{'Content'}%"
   AND xs2.xml_content_key LIKE "%[1]{'Version'}[1]{'CarrierID'}[1]{'Content'}%"
   AND xs3.xml_content_key LIKE "%[1]{'Version'}[1]{'CustomerInterface'}[1]{'Content'}%"
```

The basic idea here is that we separate the table into three tables and then put them back together. We put the Carriers in `xs1`, the CarrierIDs in `xs2`, and the CustomerInterfaces in `xs3`. Then we join these back together, putting all of the content associated with a particular `xml_key` on the same row.

**You will probably need to alter this to fit your actual schema. In particular, this query assumes that you have exactly one Carrier, CarrierID, and CustomerInterface per unique `xml_key`.** I am confident that this general approach will work if your data is anything like I've been assuming, but imperfect data would necessitate a more robust query than the example I've given here.

If you can share more details about your particular schema, I would be happy to edit my suggested query to fit your situation.

Comment: Hello William, your reply was awesome and it is looking very promising, the only thing I need to point out is that xml_key is the same for all lines, this key is like a class, in this case is xml_key 144 is for circuit so I will have this key 144 for as many circuits I have on my system. I'm now trying to make this work on my query.

Comment: @AAWW Were you able to adapt this to your query successfully? If xml_key is the same for all rows, then what is your row identifier? Would it be the index number in square brackets of your xml_content_key? I was trying to make sense of this column but I don't recognize the query language. I would assume you would use XPath or XQuery for XML, but it doesn't appear to be either of those.